# adjusting plot of a resetting time series in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a vector that has values which are increments, and that reset to 0 each time they reach the value 100.

Is there an easy way to plot the values without drawing the line from top to bottom each time the value resets to 0 ?

am currently plotting using numpy.array and the following code

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your data to separate series and plot these series individually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Y = [0,50,100,0,25,50,75,100]

split = list()
for i,y in enumerate(Y):
    if (y == 100): split += [i,]

prev = 0
for nxt in split:
    plt.plot(X[prev:nxt+1],Y[prev:nxt+1],c='b')
    prev = nxt+1

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would just add a split += [i,] just after your enumerate for loop, at line 9, to make sure i draw the last bit even if it dosent reach 100 ;)